# How to create a function that eliminates repeated elements

Tags: functions, function-construction

I want to create a function that eliminates repeated elements from a list without changing the order.

For example:

```
DeleteRepeated[{a, b, 5, a, x + y, a + b, x + y, 7, 5}]
```

should return:

```
{a, b, 5, x + y, a + b, 7}
```

How can I do that in a recursive way? I want to use less then possible the functions done from Mathematica.

PS: It is just for exercise

Comment: See [`DeleteDuplicates`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteDuplicates.html)

Comment: The [help page for `Reap[]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html#146219154) features one of the older solutions.

Comment: [This old MathGroup](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2000/Jun/msg00115.html) post (from 2000), as well as [the discussion](http://www.verbeia.com/mathematica/tips/HTMLLinks/Tricks_Misc_1.html) on _Union without sorting_ by Ted Ersek (under 'Clever Little Programs'), may be of interest.

Answer (score 2):

You can use my very old [solution](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/1999/Jun/msg00320.html) for this:

```
f[x_] := (f[x]=Sequence[]; x)

DeleteRepeated[list_] := Internal`InheritedBlock[{f},
    f /@ list
]
```

Then:

```
DeleteRepeated[{a, b, 5, a, x + y, a + b, x + y, 7, 5}]
```

> {a, b, 5, x + y, a + b, 7}

Comment: `DeleteRepeated` is a function already done from Mathematica. I want to avoid this.

Comment: @Mateus No, `DeleteRepeated` is not a built-in function, the built-in function is called `DeleteDuplicates`.

Comment: You are right. I'm sorry.

Comment: @Carl Woll In 2015, Version 10.2 introduced `Nothing`. That was after your 'very old' and clever solution. Using `Nothing`: `f[x_] := (f[x] = Nothing; x)`